# How do I remove XP without disturbing Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall, windows-xp

I have a dual booted Windows XP and Lubuntu.
I have downloaded Lubuntu through WUBI. 
In order to speed the computer up, I have decided to remove XP. 
The thing is, I don't want to disturb Lubuntu 12.04. In other words, is there any way to remove the XP partition.
If possible, please provide the proper, accurate steps on how to do so.
And if possible, please specify how to increase the partition space of my Lubuntu, which is now currently 31.1GB big.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well now that you modified the question, that changes things a bit.  Since Lubuntu was installed using WUBI, its like any other windows application, once you remove windows, everything else will be removed.  Now what I would suggest is that you backup everything that you want, and as stated in the question prior to modification, that you start fresh, and the way to do it is shown below.

**Make sure that you get a backup of all the things that you need prior to doing a fresh install.**

When you start the Ubuntu installation, and get to the installation type screen, you would choose something else, and delete the partitions that you have, and that is done by clicking on the `-` sign, and repeat for all partitions that you have.  Then create new ones by clicking on the `+` sign.

The images below show you how to get that accomplished.  Keep in mind that the partition sizes are informational only, your partition size may differ.  .

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind that swap size is recommended at twice the amount of RAM that your system have.

[image]