# ubuntu 12.04.1 lts installation problem on hp dreamscreen

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, drivers, grub2

Hi friends, I am new to Linux(Ubuntu). I have tried installing Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on a HP Dreamscreen using a usb-stick. unfortunately I had many problems like grub install fail, even if I install grub manually, a blank screen with a blinking cursor was only visible thing on screen.

> my machine info Intel Atom D525 1.8 GHz Processor,Intel NM10 Express
>   chipset,2 GB DDR3 RAM,250 GB SATA II (7200 rpm).

My question is, I have downloaded ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso file, is this compatible with my machine? I have been trying for a week to install Ubuntu. I have read many forums and referred to many web sites, many of these teach how to install along side of Windows but I want only Ubuntu to be installed on my machine.

Please, if you have any detailed solutions how to install Ubuntu, that could help me, I would be very grateful to hear them.

Comment: How did you create the USB?  Where is Grub trying to install to?

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ form universal usb installer software.i donot no where it is trying to install but it says grub installation failure fatal error.and the it says somthing about mount point has not been defined.

Comment: Verify the downloaded ISO doing an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Comment: See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303813/how-do-i-remove-xp-without-disturbing-lubuntu/303820#303820), for the installation steps, and see if that helps.

Comment: @mitch i have two machines 1 has no os and i am working on other 1 with windows os.how shall i check MD5SUM of that iso.?

Comment: i did the same thing bro.it had the same result.

Comment: Curious: why did you install the amd file since you have an intel processor. Also, I would suggest installing a 32 bit version. I suppose it should work but generally for 64 bit the entry level is 4 GB - otherwise you're not really going to get anything out of a 64 bit system - 32 bits will address your entire 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: @mikey i have added extra 2GB ram to meet the requirement.is'nt amd file right one?if it is not the right file please sugguest me with the right file.

Comment: See david6's answer below. Anyhow, I am not an expert in this but I think you should be looking for something that says x86 or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend attempting to use **64-bit** Ubuntu Linux on an **Intel *(Pineview)* Atom D525**. Most manufacturers did not enable 64-bit anyway, and performance is nothing special.

You should not be using **12.04.1 LTS**, but instead the later **12.04.2 LTS**.

---

Download **ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso**, and try that instead.

Also, look for others who have tried this on this *unusual* HP product (targeted initially at Indian market). See what they have achieved, and what (if any) issues they had with drivers.

Comment: i have referred http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=alusa_ubuntu_1210&num=1 it says 12.04.1 LTS is also ok.Can you please help me with choosing correct version of ubuntu

Comment: He just told you to install ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso.

Comment: @david6 bro this works great now.thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Ubuntu 13.10 32 bits:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

Ubuntu 64 bits is for machines with 4 gigs of ram and above and better processors.

To install Ubuntu as your only OS:

If you are now on Windows download Universal USB installer and create a USB with the 32 bit 13.10 iso.

Then change the BIOS setting to boot from USB and when you boot into the live CD press to install ubuntu and on the settings chose to delete everything and ONLY install Ubuntu.